Apply a function on a column based on condition of another column
Want to apply a logic on a column based on a condition on another column, pandas version of code is
df['cid_cm11_new'] = df.apply(lambda row: 
str(row['id']).split('.')[0].rjust(15,'0') if row['code'] == "O" else str(row['id2']).split('.')[0].rjust(9,'0'), axis=1) 

want to convert this to Pyspark logic, since my dataframe length is huge.

Use this code:
    df1 = df.withColumn(
    "cid_cm11_new",
    F.when(
        F.col("code") == "O",
        F.lpad(F.split(F.col("id"), "\.")[0], 15, "0")
    ).otherwise(
        F.lpad(F.split(F.col("id2"), "\.")[0], 9, "0")
    )
)

    display(df1)


You can use withColumn along with when and otherwise from PySpark's pyspark.sql.functions module.
from pyspark.sql.functions import when, col, lit

# Assuming your DataFrame is named `df`
df = df.withColumn(
    "cid_cm11_new",
    when(
        col("code") == "O",
        col("id").cast("string").substr(1, instr(col("id").cast("string"), ".") - 1).rjust(15, "0")
    ).otherwise(
        col("id2").cast("string").substr(1, instr(col("id2").cast("string"), ".") - 1).rjust(9, "0")
    )
)

